# When should the bias b be updated with weights w and when should it be updated seperately?

Tags: svm, logistic-regression, optimization, bias

It seems in some Machine Learning models, the bias term $b$ is updated just like other weights $w_i, i=1...n$. For example, in Logistic Regression, using SGD, $b \ \text{or} \ w_0$ is updated with:
$$b \ += LearningRate *(target - w^T*x) $$

However in SVM, $b$ is updated sperately from $w$ by using support vectors $y_s$ (i.e., $y_s(w^Tx_s+b)=1$):
$$b=y_s-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha^*_iy_ix_i^Tx_s$$
For the ML models with the linear model pattern $y=w^Tx+b$, is it only SVM updates bias $b$ seperately from $w$?